# How to call "didUpdateLocation" method from viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, swift4, cllocationmanager

I am making a weather app which gets temperature info by sending current coordinates. So I am using CLLocationManager. I haven't make any HTTP request yet. I would like to see "Location Unavailable" on my screen but it is not working.

I am following a tutorial and wrote exactly same code but in tutorial it is working. In debug session, it doesn't jump to didFailwithError or didUpdateLocations methods.I added all necessary things in my 
info.plist and my phone's location services are open. According to my research locationManager.startUpdatingLocation() should call automatically
these methods but when I run my app nothing appears on UI.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
   print("you got the location")

}

//Write the didFailWithError method here:
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print(error)
    cityLabel.text = "Location Unavaiable"
}
```

And

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager ()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //TODO:Set up the location manager here.
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You are updating location too soon, in fact before you get the permission from user.

After you ask for permission

```
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
```

Delegate method will call

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

}
```

Now its time to start updates. Guarding the status is a good idea since you don't want to start updating unless user permits it.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

        guard status == .authorizedWhenInUse else { return }
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()

}
```

Now you'll get location updates

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        print(locations)

}
```

Comment: Are you on a device or on simulator?

Comment: I am on simulator

Comment: Ok, good news. Simulator doesn't have location services, you have to simulate it as well. From Xcode menu > Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme. Choose `run` from left, on right side choose `options`. On top of the list, check `Allow Location Simulation` and choose any city as default location.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing changed. It is very interesting and annoying.

Comment: You still have your delegate set right? `locationManager.delegate = self`

Comment: Suprisingly last time I run the code it worked! Thank you for help :)